# Action of below circuit using heisenberg representation

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, quantum-circuit, pauli-gates

[image]

Can someone please explain how the above gate affects logical operators? My understanding is that the circle indicates that we are measuring the second qubit?

My initial guess is that it is equivalent to applying $Z \otimes Y$, but this would only work if the $Y$ operator was not a measurement operator I think.

If we are using the circuit to follow the evolution of say, the logical operator $Z \otimes Z$, how does $Z \otimes Z$ evolve when we apply the gate below?